# Python: How to copy files from a remote machine to local while retaining directory structure?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Source:( Remote machine) Linux server
Destination: (Local machine) windows 10

I can easily move files within local machine, while retaining folder structure using shutil.copytree

```
shutil.copytree(src, dst, copy_function=copy_dir)
```

copy_dir function filters out few files that i don't want to be included(No problem here)

Problem now is how to do i change above code such that it works when src is a remote machine folder path.

To connect to a remove server, i use SSHClient from paramiko module.